# String split via regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have a sting which contains a date, but date object wont accept it, so i have to make it into a valid format.

I tried this

```
"20130820".split(/^[a-z0-9]{4}[a-z]{2}[a-z0-9]{2}?$/)
```

It should give out an array like

```
["2013", "08", "20"]
```

Any idea where i am wrong?

Comment: what was your intention in adding [a-z] characters to the regex? Do you expect to get alphanumeric values?

Comment: Users never can be to... you get it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `.match` rather than `.split`.  You need to capture each group, and the second character class is also `a-z` when it should probably just be `\d`.

```
"20130820".match(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/).slice(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why split, you can use `String#match`:

```
var m = "20130820".match(/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/);
//=> ["20130820", "2013", "08", "20"]
```

btw for this simple job you don't need regex just use `String#substring`

Answer (score 0):

try substring

```
   String str="20130820";
   String  year=str.subString(0,3);
   String  month=str.subString(4,5);
   String  date=Str.subString(6,7);
```